# How to assign the variables used in Modelica_LinearSystems2.ModelAnalysis.Linearize?

Tags: modelica, dymola

I'd like to use `Modelica_LinearSystems2.ModelAnalysis.Linearize` to analyze the dynamic characteristics of my model, so I execute the following commands, but in the result, the variables that I am interested in don't show up.
My question is:
How could I assign the specific variables used in the function of `Modelica_LinearSystems2.ModelAnalysis.Linearize`?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That linearization is just based on the inputs, outputs, and states and you cannot change that function to linearize something else.

However, you can modify those sets of variables.

- If you want to linearize the computation of any variable you can either change it to an output or add an new output as `output Real my1=IWantToLinearize;`
- For states you can change so that some other variable is a state by using the stateSelect-attribute.
- If you want to see how a change in another variable influences the result you cannot directly make it an input, but you could replace the *use* of internal variable `xint` by `xint+u` and declare `u` as an input, to linearize w.r.t. changes here. However, you have to be careful so that the *computation* of `xint` is unchanged.